# Pagination for Views RSS

Tags: views, feeds, paging

I'm using Views RSS module to generate a custom RSS feed. I want to be able to limit the results by adding `?offset=50&limit=50` . How could I achieve that? Is there any Views plugin I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a dead simple solution. I know that by using [Services](https://drupal.org/project/services) and [Services Views](https://drupal.org/project/services_views) you can use offset and limit as arguments when calling the service.

So that the URL could look like: http://example.com/rest/views/articles?limit=5&offset=2

Comment: this way I lose the rss header/formatting